# sql/php query to set the value of a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called "users" which has columns 'username', 'password' and 'permission'. In the permission column is either 'browse' or 'edit'. 
Say I have a user logged into my site, I want to select select their permission using their username (which I have stored in a session variable). I want to then set a variable equal to either 'browse' or 'edit' based on their permission, to then use in further logic.

Assuming I have connected to and selected the appropriate database I am pretty sure the php code and query should go something like:

```
 $u = $_SESSION['username'] ;
 $sql = "SELECT permission FROM users WHERE username = '$u' " ;
 $result = mysqli_query($sql);
```

But Im unsure how to then set a variable equal to 'browse' or 'edit' accordingly.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you write user name to $_SESSION (I hope tat happens on authorization) pull and write permission with it.  `$_SESSION['user '] = ["username" => $name, "permission" => $permission];` This way you do not need to pull it on every page hit!

Comment: When all else fails you could always [Read The manual for the MYSQLI_ database extension before attempting to use it](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) __Its a RAD ideas Man__

Comment: 1) run query, 2) fetch result, 3) store result... you've got #1 above. get busy with #2,3

Comment: `Connor`, Check out my answer. well said, @RiggsFolly.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a connection `$con`, for using session you have to start your session.

```
$u = $_SESSION['username'] ;
$sql = "SELECT `permission` FROM `users` WHERE username='$u'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_object($result);

//now its time to set the permission to the variable
echo $permission = $rows->permission;
mysqli_close($con);
```

you can also set the `$permission` to a `$_SESSION`.

```
$_SESSION['permission'] = $permission;
```

Comment: And using `mysqli_fetch_object` rather than `mysqli_fetch_assoc` I like it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for encouraging me. @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$u = $_SESSION['username'] ;
$sql = "SELECT `permission` FROM `users` WHERE username='$u'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_object($result);

//now its time to set the permission to the variable
echo $permission = $rows->permission;
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: What does this add to @FrayneKonok answer other than Plagurism ?

Comment: *Atif Bhai* What's difference between your and Mr. Frayne Answer. ?

Comment: @NanaPartykar bhai, i also add  DataBase connection code.

Comment: @NanaPartykar may i have to remove my answer?

Comment: @NanaPartykar, Thanks hahaha Support Islamabad United. Any reason??